# DayRender cell changes lost when a new date is selected

Tags: asp.net, calendar, background-color

I am changing the background color for individual cells in the DayRender control, but when I select a different date the background color i chose for the cells are lost. I've looked around and can't really find what I am looking for. Hopefully the code will make it a bit more clear on what I want my code to do.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{String sFullDate, sTradacomsDate;
    XmlNode node;

    sFullDate = e.Day.Date.Day.ToString("00") + "/" + e.Day.Date.Month.ToString("00") + "/" + e.Day.Date.Year.ToString();
    sTradacomsDate = e.Day.Date.Year.ToString().Substring(2,2) + e.Day.Date.Month.ToString("00") + e.Day.Date.Day.ToString("00");

    if (xmlDoc != null)
    {
        node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Dates/dbo.ASNs[FileDate = '" + sFullDate + "']");

        if (node != null)
        {
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen;
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
    } 
    if (xmlDoc2 != null)
    {
        node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Dates/dbo.Orders[DateOrderPlaced = '" + sTradacomsDate + "']");

        if (node != null)
        {
            if (e.Cell.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }
            else 
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have ViewState enabled for the control. When you select a date it performs a post back to handle the event; if ViewState is off and you don't reset the cell colors, they will revert to the default state. Make sure `EnableViewState="true"` is enabled at the page, user control, and Calendar control levels.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have the enableviewstate set to true but the background color is still going back to the default background-color when the date is changed.

Comment: Can you post more of your source? For example, are you sure that xmlDoc and xmlDoc2 are not null during the postback? It's common to have if (!IsPostBack) in the Page_Load--are you doing that so that the data sources aren't getting set correctly as Calendar1_DayRender is assumed? Have you debugged and set a breakpoint to make sure the if block are running as expected during the postbacks?

Comment: Ahh Im so stupid, my xmldocuments were null on reload because they were wrapped up in !isPostBack as you mentioned.
Thanks for that!